# Multiple authentication methods in asp.Net core 2.2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a way to use JWT bearer authentication AND a custom authentication method in .net core?  I want all actions to default to JWT, except in a few cases where I want to use a custom authentication header.

Comment: the issue seems straight forward. Have you looked into the docs? Can you show what you have tried so far and where you were stuck? if you are not sure where to start you can check the official docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it.  This example uses JWT authentication by default and custom authentication in certain rare cases.  Please note, from what I've read, Microsoft seems to discourage writing your own auth. Please use at your own risk.

First, add this code to the startup.cs ConfigureServices method to ensure that authentication gets applied globally.

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
```

Then, add this to configure the schemes you wish to use (in our case JWT and Custom).

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    // Jwt Authentication
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Audience = ".......";
        options.Authority = "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_...";
    })
    // Custom auth
    .AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, 
        CustomAuthHandler>(CustomAuthOptions.DefaultScheme, options => { });
```

Next create a class to hold your custom authentication options:

```
public class CustomAuthOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public const string Scheme = "custom auth";
    public const string CustomAuthType = "custom auth type";
}
```

Finally, add an authentication handler to implement the custom authentication logic.

```
public class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, 
        UrlEncoder encoder, 
        ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // Auth logic goes here
        if (!Request.Headers....) 
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authentication Failed."));
        }

        // Create authenticated user
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = .... ;

        List<ClaimsIdentity> identities = 
            new List<ClaimsIdentity> {
                new ClaimsIdentity(CustomAuthOptions.CustomAuthType)};

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = 
            new AuthenticationTicket(
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identities), CustomAuthOptions.Scheme);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

Finally, to tie it all together, add an authorize attribute to the actions you wish to use custom authorization on.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CustomAuthOptions.Scheme)]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    ....
}
```

Now JWT authentication will automatically get applied to all actions, and custom authentication will get added to only the actions with the Authorize attribute set to the custom scheme.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: for instance, basic auth: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/08/aspnet-core-21-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: This naswer is extermely helpful: "Use multiple JWT Bearer Authentication" https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706390/218651