# Different authentication for different sub directories in ASP.NET Core 3.1 webapp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is there any way to configure a .NET core Razor Pages app to have no authentication required for the root directory, basic uid/password authentication for one subdirectory, and Azure B2C for different subdirectory:

```
/
/basicauth
/aadb2c
```

I have seen one for [basic uid/password](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/335/simple-authentication-in-razor-pages-without-a-database) which sets the startup.cs looking like this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/admin");
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

...and in a ones for [Azure b2c looks](https://elanderson.net/2019/04/asp-net-core-with-azure-b2c-auth/) which protect the whole app. Judging by the services configuration above, it looks like only one type of Authorization can be used. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe, authentication is injected at the root, and there, I think, only authentication service is allowed. hopefully, you will get additional confirmation or contradictions from others.

Comment: For one asp.net application using different auth on different folder is not provided out of box. It is possible to support multiple auth on whole app then restricting access on resources/folders based on roles or auth

Comment: Thank you. If you put this as an answer I will check it.

Comment: Agree with PranavSingh, you could use multiple auth in one application, try to use different Authentication Schemes, then, in the page, using Authorize attribute and assign the schemes, reference: [Multiple authentication methods in asp.Net core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260837/), [ASP.NET Core: Supporting multiple Authorization](https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-supporting-multiple-authorization-6502eb79f934) and [Use multiple authentication schemes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Done. You've convinced me. If you want to put this in an answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As PranavSingh said: *it is possible to support multiple auth on whole app then restricting access on resources/folders based on roles or auth*.

Besides, you could try to use different Authentication Schemes, then, in the page, using `[Authorize]` attribute and assign the schemes,

Reference:

[Multiple authentication methods in asp.Net core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260837/),

[ASP.NET Core: Supporting multiple Authorization](https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-supporting-multiple-authorization-6502eb79f934)

[Use multiple authentication schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1).