# Auto Signin after Signing up using invitation signup policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-static-web-app

I am not this guy but I experience the same thing [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/246). Also, there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68035261/auto-logged-in-after-signing-up-using-invitation-signup-policy) but the author there uses a different flow, so I don't really know if it fits.

In short, I implemented the flow [invite-via-email](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite-via-email). I could generate the invitation link and the user could click on the link to sign up.

However, after signing up, the user is redirected to the main login page again. The user has to type the credentials again to sign in.

How can I implement auto signing after the user sign up with the invite-via-email flow?

There is a comment on that GitHub thread about `id_token_hint` something but I honestly do not get it. Many thanks.

If it helps, my setup is Azure Static Webapp with Svelte for frontend and Azure Functions for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the access token from the first login? You might not be, forcing you to log in again. Also, do you have [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on) enabled? This may help you if not. Please let me know and I can help you further.

Best,
James

Comment: The SSO link is about normal AD, the question is about B2C. Is enabling SSO relevant to B2C? If yes, how it can be enabled?