Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10516: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:
I have a info message logged in console while running my dotnet 3.1 application.
    Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10516: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:
kid: 'X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.NotSupportedException: IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.
Algorithm: 'RS256', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: 'gKr5A9SR7evTiiQfjT0W6wjH3YMAFRD0SYhQ0o8LQ14'.'
 is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, Boolean cacheProvider)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForVerifying(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean cacheProvider)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForVerifying(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)
         at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(Byte[] encodedBytes, Byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, String algorithm, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
         at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)

This is logged as an info message and my authentication is working fine also. What is this saying us? I am using Azure AD B2C.
What could be the reason for this?
Saw similar questions in stackoverflow. But its not resolving my issues.
Here is my code
This is how I generate my token
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var claims = new[]
    {
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,user.userid),
    new Claim("subject","my subject"),
    new Claim("fullName",user.FirstName+" "+user.LastName),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
};

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _config["JWTIssuer"],
        audience: _config["JWTAudience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        signingCredentials: credentials
        );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

And here is my configureservices method
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C", "MyAzureADB2CScheme");

services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = authUrl,
        ValidAudience = authUrl,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
    };
});

Please see the JWT decoded data.


...show code...

And what is the scope you are passing?

@ProgrammingLlama added required code.

@Rukmini How can I do that?

@JyothishBhaskaran Can you decode the access token in https://jwt.ms and paste it by masking the values. I just want to see the aud and scp values

@Rukmini jwt added.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856735/idx10501-signature-validation-failed-unable-to-match-keys use ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,      IssuerSigningKeys = openidconfig.SigningKeys,

@Rukmini Checking. One moment please.

Is that  comment still valid? I am getting an error from Program.cs Main Method after making these changes. No inner exception. @Rukmini

Yes I guess so Is still the error exists?

Yes. Problem is for Azure AD B2C I should use AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi method but here they are using AddJwtBearer method. Looks like they are not using Azure AD B2C.
