# Defining a WebAPI with two JWT authentication schemes does not work

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

For an ASP.NET WebAPI I'm trying to establish two authentication schemes (for JWTs) to protect different resources, since I cannot use a single authentication (for silly reasons, but I cannot do anything about it right now). Theoretically allowing two different schemes should be relatively straight forward, but for some reason it is not and I do not know what else I could try to make it work (basically, I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes) guide). My approach was to call `AddJwtBearer` twice in my setup with two different schemes

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(
        options =>
            {
                // ...
            })
    .AddJwtBearer(
        AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme, 
        options =>
            {
                options.Challenge = AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme;
                // ...
            });
```

Furthermore I added

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(
    options =>
        {
            var customPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

            var azureAdPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            
            options.AddPolicy(AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme, customPolicy);
            options.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, azureAdPolicy);

            options.DefaultPolicy = customPolicy;
        });
```

to my setup and

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme)]
```

to my controller method.

Anyway, authorization with `CustomScheme` does not work. The scheme/policy seems to be functional (theoretical), for if I pass the `Authorization` header with my custom scheme, the `WWW-Authenticate` header matches my type, but I always get a `401 Unauthorized`. When I add

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

to any controller method and pass a valid token for the configuration, I get a `200 OK`. I've checked the configuration for validating the tokens two and three times, but it seems okay. To me, the implementation seems broken, but then [online people claim that something very similar worked out for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61214972/use-two-jwt-authentication-scheme-asp-net-core-3-1). Am I missing something?

Comment: did you tried giving policy instead of AuthenticationSchemes as mentioned in the link ?

Comment: @CodingMytra Yeah, I have given it a shot.

Comment: as I understand both are jwt based auth, then why to go for this pain of writing this much code. if you remove `options.Challenge = AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme;` line from your code then it will work fine and without any additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously - at least as far as I can tell - the documentation is wrong. Or there is a bug, which renders the documentation effectively wrong. The code the `JwtBearerHandler` uses to obtain the token from the `Authorization` header is

```cs
if (authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    token = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
}

// If no token found, no further work possible
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
{
    return AuthenticateResult.NoResult(); 
}
```

So obviously it does not take a different authentication scheme into account, which seems quite a bit odd, for the `AddJwtBearer` extension method **does** allow a custom scheme to be passed (see my original code or the linked documentation). Anyway, if the `OnMessageReceived` event resolves a token and assigns the `MessageReceivedContext.Token`, the `JwtBearerHandler` will use this token:

```cs
// Give application opportunity to find from a different location, adjust, or reject token
var messageReceivedContext = new MessageReceivedContext(Context, Scheme, Options);

// event can set the token
await Events.MessageReceived(messageReceivedContext);
if (messageReceivedContext.Result != null)
{
    return messageReceivedContext.Result;
}

// If application retrieved token from somewhere else, use that.
token = messageReceivedContext.Token;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
// ...
```

So I ended up installing a handler that looks for my custom authentication scheme and assigns the token if the scheme was used:

```cs
.AddJwtBearer(
AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme,
options =>
    {
        options.Challenge = AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme;

        /* options */

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                             {
                                 OnMessageReceived = context =>
                                     {
                                         if (TryGetToken(
                                                 context.Request,
                                                 AuthenticationDefaults.CustomScheme,
                                                 out string? token))
                                         {
                                             context.Token = token;
                                         }

                                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                                     }
                             };


    });
    
// ...
    
bool TryGetToken(HttpRequest httpRequest, string authenticationScheme, out string? token)
{
    var authorization = httpRequest.Headers?.Authorization;

    if (authorization is { Count: >= 1 } 
        && authorization.Value[0].StartsWith(authenticationScheme))
    {
        token = authorization.Value[0].Substring(authenticationScheme.Length)
            .Trim();
        return true;
    }

    token = null;
    return false;
}
```

(From the [`JwtBearerHandler` code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v6.0.8/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs).)