# Trigger Custom Authentication Scheme For Antonymous Method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an action method which is anonymous.

I have cookie authentication scheme and JWT bearer scheme. Cookie is the default authentication scheme.

Now, in my action method if I specify the JWT authentication scheme then token validated and user is authenticated user.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult Get()
```

If the method is antonymous then JWT token is not validated and user is antonymous,

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Get()
```

Is there way to trigger the JWT and cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post which allows me to fix this issue [Use multiple JWT Bearer Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694383/use-multiple-jwt-bearer-authentication)

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
                .Build();
            });
```